# Why eclipse is not showing warning if a declared class variable is not used anywhere in program

Tags: java, eclipse

If I declare a local variable and do not use it anywhere, eclipse shows error

> The value of the local variable  is not used

But if I declare a class variable and not using it anywhere, no such warning is shown. Why is that?

Comment: Because it might be used in another class. If it doesn't have external visibility, then you'll get the same warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the class variable is not private, Eclipse assumes it will be accessed outside of this class, either within the project or by an external project. If the class variable is private and is not used within the class then the warning will be shown.

Comment: Small addition to this absolutely correct answer: if you have some doubts about visibility of class, method or variable, you may try Unused Code Detector plugin from Eclipse Market. Very useful in big projects.